# QML osm Plugin draw both path & items

Tags: qt, qml, openstreetmap

How can I draw both item icons & path between points from model using QML and osm plugin?

```
XmlListModel {
    ...
}

Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
    objectName: "mapPlugin"
    name: "osm"
    ...
}

Map {
    id: map
    objectName: "map"

    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin

    MapItemView {
        id: mapItemView
        model: mapModel

        // draw item icons
        delegate: MapQuickItem {
            coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate( model.latitude, model.longitude )
            ...
        }

        // could draw lines between points, but unable to use two delegates
        /* delegate: MapPolyline {
            path: pathRole

            line.color: "red"
            line.width: 5
        } */
}
```

Comment: It's unclear how do you define your model but actually you can define 2 kinds of model items - points and lines and select a needed delegate with [DelegateChooser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechooser.html)

Comment: @folibis currently there is no explicit role for `MapQuickItem` only the line `coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate( model.latitude, model.longitude )`. How can I apply role for `MapQuickItem` delegate?

Comment: No, I mean you have to declare a role for each model item and so according to this role you choose an appropriate delegate using DelegateChooser. Sure you have to define 2 delegates as well.

Comment: @folibis all model items have the same type

Comment: well, you somehow want to separate paths and elements. right?

Comment: @folibis yes. Currently every data item contains coordinates. I just want to draw both path & items based on the coordinates

Comment: Perhaps you can mock a screenshot what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You could use two `MapItemView` with the same model one drawing the route the other drawing the icons on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick you could do is create two MapItemViews. One for drawing the icons and the other for drawing line segments connecting the two, i.e.

```
    MapItemView { // for drawing icons
        model: mapModel
    }
    MapItemView { // for drawing line segments
        model: mapModel.count - 1
    }
```

Here's a sample of how you may do this:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtPositioning 5.15
Page {
    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }
    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(43.0896, -79.0849)
        zoomLevel: 12
        MapItemView {
            model: mapModel
            delegate: MapQuickItem {
                coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(lat, lon)
                anchorPoint.x: 5
                anchorPoint.y: 5
                sourceItem: Rectangle {
                    width: 10
                    height: 10
                    color: "red"
                    border.color: "black"
                }
            }
        }
        MapItemView {
            model: mapModel.count - 1
            delegate: MapPolyline {
                line.width: 3
                line.color: "green"
                path: [
                    { latitude: mapModel.get(index).lat, longitude: mapModel.get(index).lon },
                    { latitude: mapModel.get(index + 1).lat, longitude: mapModel.get(index + 1).lon }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: mapModel
        function appendCoordinate(lat, lon) {
            append( {lat, lon} );
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            appendCoordinate(43.0896, -79.0849);
            appendCoordinate(43.0796, -79.0849);
            appendCoordinate(43.0796, -79.0949);
        }
    }
}
```